# Android Studio Installation procedure

Tags: java, android

I have downloaded Android Studio and when I installed it and tried my first project then a lot of errors occured.Now being a newbie I want to ask you a couple of questions.

1. Is it necessary to be connected to the Internet while installing the bundle because I was offline at the time when I installed the bundle.A message was shown which states that"Unable to access the SDK add on list".I cleared that message.

2.If I need to be connected to the Internet then how fast the net connection needs to be?I am specially asking this because currently my wifi network is not working and I am using mobile data which has a crappy speed.

3.Any necessary steps which needs to be followed while installing?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html

Comment: I have followed those steps but that did not helped me.Actually those error messages are really frustrating.